# How to parse and format YouTube API data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, youtube

I used the Youtube_IT gem to get some search results for a simple one page search result application. The problem is that the results are coming out like this:

```
Emperor penguins - The Greatest Wildlife Show on Earth - BBC  [#<YouTubeIt::Model::Thumbnail:0x3fcb790 @url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/MfstYSUscBc/default.jpg", @height=90, @width=120, @time="00:02:07", @name="default">, #<YouTubeIt::Model::Thumbnail:0x3fcaf08 @url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/MfstYSUscBc/mqdefault.jpg", @height=180, @width=320, @time=nil, @name="mqdefault">, #<YouTubeIt::Model::Thumbnail:0x3fc9c30 @url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/MfstYSUscBc/hqdefault.jpg", @height=360, @width=480, @time=nil, @name="hqdefault">, #<YouTubeIt::Model::Thumbnail:0x3fc91e0 @url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/MfstYSUscBc/1.jpg", @height=90, @width=120, @time="00:01:03.500", @name="start">, #<YouTubeIt::Model::Thumbnail:0x3fd0020 @url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/MfstYSUscBc/2.jpg", @height=90, @width=120, @time="00:02:07", @name="middle">, #<YouTubeIt::Model::Thumbnail:0x3fcf948 @url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/MfstYSUscBc/3.jpg", @height=90, @width=120, @time="00:03:10.500", @name="end">] Penguin Fail - Best Bloopers from Penguins Spy in the Huddle (Waddle all the Way) [#<YouTubeIt::Model::Thumbnail:0x3e180d0 @url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Tcx6YyXvvRI/default.jpg", @height=90, @width=120, @time="00:00:42.500", @name="default">, #<YouTubeIt::Model::Thumbnail:0x3e17e00 @url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Tcx6YyXvvRI/mqdefault.jpg", @height=180, @width=320, @time=nil, @name="mqdefault">, #<YouTubeIt::Model::Thumbnail:0x3e17b18 @url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Tcx6YyXvvRI/hqdefault.jpg", @height=360, @width=480, @time=nil, @name="hqdefault">, #<YouTubeIt::Model::Thumbnail:0x3e17830 @url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Tcx6YyXvvRI/sddefault.jpg", @height=480, @width=640, @time=nil, @name="sddefault">, #<YouTubeIt::Model::Thumbnail:0x3e17560 @url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Tcx6YyXvvRI/1.jpg", @height=90, @width=120, @time="00:00:21.250", @name="start">, #<YouTubeIt::Model::Thumbnail:0x3e17248 @url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Tcx6YyXvvRI/2.jpg", @height=90, @width=120, @time="00:00:42.500", @name="middle">, #<YouTubeIt::Model::Thumbnail:0x3e16ca8 @url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/Tcx6YyXvvRI/3.jpg", @height=90, @width=120, @time="00:01:03.750", @name="end">] Octonauts The Great Penguin Race HD A [#<YouTubeIt::Model::Thumbnail:0x40ccb90 @url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/_6AR61XbeCI/default.jpg", @height=90, @width=120, @time="00:10:59", @name="default">, #<YouTubeIt::Model::Thumbnail:0x40cc8a8 @url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/_6AR61XbeCI/mqdefault.jpg", @height=180, @width=320, @time=nil, @name="mqdefault">, #<YouTubeIt::Model::Thumbnail:0x40cc608 @url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/_6AR61XbeCI/hqdefault.jpg", @height=360, @width=480, @time=nil, @name="hqdefault">, #<YouTubeIt::Model::Thumbnail:0x40cc350 @url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/_6AR61XbeCI/1.jpg", @height=90, @width=120, @time="00:05:29.500", @name="start">, #<YouTubeIt::Model::Thumbnail:0x40cc080 @url="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/_6AR61XbeCI/2.jpg", @height=90, @width=120, @time="00:10:59", @name="middle">, #
```

What can I do to make it more readable?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a table solved this! Just having issues with the thumbnails displaying, but I guess I solved my question. Thanks everyone that viewed!